# GitHub Boxen Error

Tags: github, installation

I'm not the biggest user of GitHub and when I try and install their new "boxen" (https://github.com/boxen/our-boxen) I'm having issues.

The `README.md` has instructions and I'm getting an error when running

```
git checkout -b master upstream/master
```

Any ideas? I created a local repo if that's any difference, or would I need to make one on GitHub?

Error message:

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

Comment: So, did the previous commands complete successfully? You didn't do something like `git init --bare` instead of just plain `git init`?

Comment: yeah i did --bare. should i have not have?